# From all the files that their name is composed of 4 letters, which contain the string “user” in their content?

Tags: shell, unix, command, command-substitution

I have to answer this question as an exercise.

1. Sample input: No sample, just trying to select and filter files using Unix shell according to some conditions
2. Sample output: a list of files that their name is composed of 4 letters and which contain the string “user” in their content.
3. I tried to use the `basename ~/` command to get the file name of some files, then tried to combine it with `wc` by doing, for example, `basename /etc/ |wc -c`.
   Finally, I tried `grep user file_test.txt` on an arbitrary file to see if it contains the word "user".

I am trying to combine all the required commands to answer the question.

I am supposed to use substitutions which I am not used to.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. On SO we encourage users to add 3 important things in their question. 1st- Sample of input, 2nd- sample of output, 3rd- their efforts. So please add these things in your question(not in comments please) and let us know then.

Comment: I think it is ok now

Comment: Like this?: `grep -i user ????`

Comment: There seem to be a couple of aspects here... determining which files to search in (try Googling *"bash wildcards"*) and searching in a file for the word `"user"` (try `man grep`).

Comment: If all the files you're looking for are in your current directory, `grep -Fl user ????` should do it.